# how to split a string by the first instance of '<p>'

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the example below I need to split the string by the first instance of `<p>`
so the first element should be `lorem ipsum` and the second one - everything behind

```js
var str = "lorem ipsum<p>dolor sit</p><p>amet</p>";
var start = str.split("<p>:first")[0]; // something like that
console.log(start); // should be `lorem ipsum`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: since you are only interested in the first split, your code works just using `"<p>"` as the split argument

Comment: @Bravo - no, the second element should be everything behind the first `<p>`

Comment: but your code doesn't care about anything but the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make everything that comes after the `<p>` a capturing group, and it'll be included in the match as another item:

```js
var str = "lorem ipsum<p>dolor sit</p><p>amet</p>";
var start = str.split(/<p>(.*)/).filter(Boolean);
console.log(start); // should be `lorem ipsum`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: or simply, `str.split("<p>")[0]`

Comment: That'll split along all `<p>`s, not just the first, which it sounded like OP didn't want

Comment: yeah, but his code only deals with the first element :p

Comment: no, that wouldn't be it since console.log returns `undefined` @qadenza

Comment: @Bravo - I'm getting `lorem ipsum` in my console

Comment: then you must be doing `console.log(start[0])` not what you said

Answer (score 3):

`split` by all the `"<p>"` instances then take the first one and `join` the rest by `"<p>"`, use a [destructring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make things simple like so:

```
let [start, ...rest] = str.split("<p>");
rest = rest.join("<p>");
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "lorem ipsum<p>dolor sit</p><p>amet</p>";

let [start, ...rest] = str.split("<p>");
rest = rest.join("<p>");

console.log("start: " + start);
console.log("rest: " + rest);
```

Comment: interesting, but may be simpler just `split` than `split` and `join`

Comment: depends on what's your definition of "simpler" is. Using `split` alone will require you to use a regex like @CertainPerformance's answer. It's up to you to decide which is simpler, a regex or a `join`